# Why is df.info().to_csv('File_name.csv') returning error?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to save `df.info()` into a `.csv` file.

I tried using this:

```
df.info().to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

However receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Any ideas for saving the `df.info()` to a `.csv`?

Answer (score 1):

`df.info()` is a method that doesn't actually return anything. Instead, (from the pandas docs) it "Prints a concise summary of a DataFrame." This means that you are running `df.info()` (which returns `None`) and then trying to call `to_csv()` on that.

Saving `df.info()` as a csv will be difficult, given the output is actually *not* a table. It *contains* a table, but also contains info such as

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 3 columns):
```

and

```
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 22.9+ MB
```

You **can save the entire output to a text file** as mentioned in the pandas documentation:

```py
with open('info.txt', 'w') as f:
    df.info(buf=f)
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

```
import io
buffer = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
s = buffer.getvalue()
with open("df_info.txt", "w",encoding="utf-8") as f:  
f.write(s)
```

According to the pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html this is how you can write df.info to a file.

If you wish to write it to a CSV, you can replace the
`with open("df_info.txt", "w",encoding="utf-8") as f`
With
`with open("df_info.csv", "w",encoding="utf-8") as f`

Answer (score 0):

`df.info()` prints a summary of the dataframe and returns `None`. And that doesn't have any method `to_csv`.

But from you question I guess you are looking fro something like this:

```py
with open('output.txt','w') as out:
  df.info(buf = out)
```

Comment: This does not save as a valid CSV. In fact, this just saves a text file with the **csv** extension.

Comment: sorry, that was by mistake. Simply copies df.info and will paste in the file